# Passing through ng-content to ng-template element in child component doesn't bind to properties

Tags: angular, angular-ngselect

I have a component called **select.component** (selector: 'app-select') which searches for users using typeahead (I left this out for simplicity). I then want to show the name and employeeId by binding to item in ng-template.

```html
<ng-select>
  <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item">
    {{item.name}}</br>
    {{item.employeeId}}
  </ng-template
</ng-select>
```

As we use many of these ng-select elements in the app, I have made select.component a reusable component which other parent components use. I therefore want to make the ng-template part dynamic and have it passed in from the parent component. I have changed select.component to look like this instead:

```html
<ng-select>
  <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </ng-template
</ng-select>
```

I then have **user.component** which uses content projection to populate ng-template in the select.component like so:

```html
<app-select>
  {{item.name}}</br>
  {{item.employeeId}}
</app-select>
```

The problem here is that by the time content projection has passed the inner html of app-select to ng-template, {{item.name}} and {{item.employeeId}} are not evaluated within the ng-template. In the dropdown of items, I see {{item.name}}, rather than the actual name value.

How could I best achieve this? I really need parent components to be able to specify how the dropdown items should appear to make select.component fully reusable.

See my [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6mgo6j?embed=1&file=src/app/user/user.component.html&view=preview)

Comment: @ChellappanV Please see the link at the bottom of the question

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass the code in    component and catch in select component

```
<app-select>
  <ng-select [items]="items" bindLabel="name" placeholder="Works">
    <ng-template ng-option-tmp let-item="item">
        {{item.name}}<br/>
        {{item.employeeId}}
  </ng-template>
</ng-select>
</app-select>
```

Then you need  to use

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
```

in your select component

This way you will be able to achive what you want.

Comment: This is what I did to begin with but I need to pass in the inner HTML of ng-template from the parent to achieve what I want

Comment: can you check now

Comment: I don't think you quite understand what I'm trying to do but thanks for your answer

Comment: wait i will go through again sorry about misunderstanding

Answer (score 1):

I agree it is helpful to encapsulate common setup in a component and allow for the rest of the setup to be provided by the consumer of the component.

NgSelect uses `@ContentChild()` to get templates provided within the component tag when the parent is providing them. I suspect `<ng-content>` is not yet available because the `ngAfterContentInit` lifecycle hook is called before `ngAfterViewInit`.

Another approach would be to accept a `TemplateRef` as an input to your `<app-select>` and set NgSelect's `optionTemplate` manually, after the view has initialized:

```
export class SelectComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input() items: any[];
  @Input() optionTemplate: TemplateRef<any>; // The options template to provide to ng-select

  @ViewChild(NgSelectComponent) ngSelect: NgSelectComponent; // A reference to the ng-select component

  // Once @ViewChild is defined after view init
  ngAfterViewInit() {
    if (this.optionTemplate) {
      // Manually assign ng-select's optionTemplate from the input
      this.ngSelect.optionTemplate = this.optionTemplate;
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can pass in a template you can reference via a reference variable:

```
<app-select [items]="items" [optionTemplate]="appSelectOption">
</app-select>

<ng-template #appSelectOption let-item="item">
  {{item.name}}<br/>
  {{item.employeeId}}
</ng-template>
```

This way you can keep the template outlet context (`let-item="item"`) in the same area where you are using the variable.

See a [fork of your StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-o7oa27)

Answer (score 0):

ng-template is never ever work without any stucture directive or template ref variable. you can use ng-container instead of ng-template.sorry any thing is missing coz i have answered this question from my cell phone